# Integration PHP + Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, quotes, double-quotes, quote

I have a problem with integrations in the php code in javascript within single quotes

I need to put the variable `$video` that will get the id of a YT video, instead of the id of the video `**VARIABLEVIDEOHER**E`, but I tried all ways to put single and double quotes did not work to integrate more, someone could give me a light

```
<?php $video = 'BYN-DEM7Mzw';
$desc = '<script type="text/javascript">
function youtubeFeedCallback( data ){
document.writeln( data.entry[ "media$group" ][ "media$description" ].$t.replace( /\n/g, "<br/>" ) + "<br/>" ); }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VARIAVELVIDEOAQUI?v=2&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=youtubeFeedCallback"></script>';
echo $desc; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
<?php $video = 'BYN-DEM7Mzw';
$desc = '<script type="text/javascript">
function youtubeFeedCallback( data ){
document.writeln( data.entry[ "media$group" ][ "media$description" ].$t.replace( /\n/g, "<br/>" ) + "<br/>" ); }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'.$video.'?v=2&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=youtubeFeedCallback"></script>';
echo $desc; ?>
```

It seems you are just trying to insert the variable in a string, not really a javascript problem. As a side note, copying code from the internet without actually understanding what it does is genuinely *bad*, and generally leads to unmaintainable spaghetti code that breaks easily, but that's a different issue.

Comment: just that you need, worked perfect
I ask forgiveness because I really do not understand programming.

Comment: Well then don't program :) If you want to mess around with PHP you will have to learn how to program, PHP is a programming language and saying I don't understand programming is no excuse to produce code that breaks. If you wanted to drive a car, normally you would learn how to drive car first before driving, right? otherwise you would crash the car.

Comment: so they can understand my question, I need to get the description of a video from youtube through the id of the video and save this description in a custom field with the same formatting youtube

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_encode()` to  turn the string into a JavaScript literal, and then add it to the rest of the string.

```
var foo = "bar" + <?php echo json_encode('quux'); ?>;
```

Comment: I'm new to php and javascript, if it is not asking too much could put together exactly how the code would get your answer, thank you

Comment: Can you not adapt the example given in the answer?

Comment: json code found on the web, do not quite understand, I just want to adapt it receives the id of the video of a variable and do not know how to do

Comment: Clever answer though. OP clearly didn't have a javascript problem but it's interesting that you can json_encode values directly.